# GNU parallel double-dashed options not working

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run the following very simple parallel script:

```
 parallel --eta -j 1 -- "echo hi"
```

but I get an error

```
parallel: invalid option -- '-'
parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
    for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
    run specified commands in parallel
```

This happens for every double-dashed option I try to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Tollef's parallel from Moreutils, and not GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Tollef's parallel then try this:

- Run `whereis parallel` to get the path of parallel exec binary in your system. Run using the absolute path returned by this command.

**Optionally**, you can add an alias for this in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file like:

`alias parallel='/usr/local/bin/parallel'`